# perl print array from subroutine

Tags: perl, arrays, foreach, subroutine

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl 
sub getClusters
{
my @clusters = `/qbo/bin/getclusters|grep -v 'qboc33'`;
chomp(@clusters);
return \@clusters;
}
```

ummm okay .. how do I get at this array to print since ...

```
foreach $cluster (getClusters())
{ print $cluster."\n"; }
```

doesn't seem to work. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should be seeing something like ARRAY(0x80177c) (or some other hex value), right? If so, Amadan's answer is correct. If you are getting some error or a different type of output, you should add it to your question.

Comment: You are missing `use strict; use warnings;` in your code.

Comment: You will get better responses to your questions if you give more information about the problem than "doesn't seem to work".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a reference, and not dereferencing it anywhere.

```
foreach $cluster (@{getClusters()})
```

OR

```
return @clusters;
```

Either should fix it (with slightly different effects), with the first one being preferred (your array is kind of big).

You'd use the non-referenced array return for limited number of elements, usually for the purpose of multi-return (thus, usually, limited to 2 or 3, known-length arrays).

Comment: -1, returning an array over an arrayref is bad advice.  Remove that part and +1

Comment: @vol7ron: Not advice, I just said what will work. You do have a point, however. I made it explicit when to use which. (Returning an array has its place, thus I prefer to clarify instead of remove.)

Comment: +1. There's nothing at all wrong with returning an array. There are lots of things to consider, such as the typical array size, and how the sub will behave in context.

Comment: +1 returned for your edit.  I want to also correct my comment: my comment, a list is being returned, not an array. Still, there is a performance hit, where one doesn't need to occur, as minimal as it is, arrayrefs should still be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

If you ran your program under `use strict; use warnings;`, it would have told you why it failed. As Amadan said, you need to dereference the reference you return.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl Solution

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

main();

sub main{
   {
      local $"    =  "\n";
      print "@{getClusters()}";
   }
}  

sub getClusters{
   my @tArray  =  `/qbo/bin/getclusters|grep -v 'qboc33'`;
   chomp @tArray;
   return \@tArray;
}
```

#### Notice

1. You don't need a `foreach` loop for debugging, you can just reset the `$"` operator however to separate array elements however you like (eg,  , `,` , or how I set it in the code above `\n`).
2. Returning an array ref is a plus, don't send back the full array (good job)
3. use strict/warnings, especially when debugging
4. try to avoid system calls using ``` `` ```

Comment: I still like this solution better as it introduces the `$"`, one of the more uncommon special variables, which reduces the need for a loop in this case.

Comment: But you modify `$"` over the entire program.  `local` means that `getClusters` and anything it calls will see the modified value.  With something as heavily used as `$"`, you are begging to break a larger program.  If you must munge globals, restrict the effects as tightly as possible.  This is much safer: `my $clusters = getClusters(); { local $" = "\n"; print @$clusters; }`

Comment: **@daotoad:** You made an excellent point, which I credited, however that is why local was used - it only applies it to the main function and any subroutine called within it.  **Note:** your `@$clusers` needs to be contained in a set of double quotes (`""`).  Also, `$"` is not used that heavily, primarily in debugging.  **Update:** I've modified the code, if `getClusters()` is a special case that requires the `$"` to be at it's default, it can define `$"=' '` inside it.  Otherwise, limiting to a sub-block of main is fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is being downvoted, it is superior in explanation and example.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy, you can first receive the return value and then print it like

```
use strict;
use warning;
my $cluster_array = getClusters();
 my @cluster_return = @{$cluster_array};
foreach my $cluster(@cluster_return){
 print"$cluster\n";
}
```